# Handling reviewer comment challenging the novelty of a used method

Tags: publications, peer-review

One of the Reviewer comments for a paper that I sent to a journal is the following:

> The authors claim that they are the first to use subjective
>   questionnaires  to develop predictive models. This is not accurate, there
>   are many studies on the literature that use questionnaires  and some of
>   them even compare PQ to objective data coming from sensors in order to
>   find correlations.

Now the problem is that I have done a thorough check and have observed that this paper indeed is first to use questionnaire to develop predicitve models for the particular disorder. Now how do I handle such a comment?

Comment: It seems that you are not the first to have used the method. Rather is the first time for a particular disorder.  I wouldn't stress "we are the first using SQ to. ....." which gives emphasis to method novelty but rather " we are the first obtaining a predictive model for particular disorder using the SQ meth". Obviously I am not writing for your paper :) I just suggest the cut that your paper should probably have.

Answer (score 4):

I think there's no contradiction. The reviewer said "...first to use subjective questionnaires to develop predictive models", while you said "...first to use subjective questionnaires to develop predictive models *for the particular disorder*" (emphasis mine).

I would just write in a response what you said, and ask for clarification - something like "I have done a thorough check ... the particular disorder. If the reviewer is aware of a previous paper has also used subjective questionnaires for this disorder, please point it out".

Comment: The reviewer have actually pointed out some references defending his point. But they do not use questionnaire to develop predictive models and use different data or analysis.

Answer (score 3):

It may be the case that your paper is the first to use this method for a very specific area/field/subject/topic. If so, it may be unclear to the reader that it is the first in *that* sense.

You may try to argue that, if there is a rebut option; if not, try to make it clearer on the text for the final version if it gets accepted.